# How to move a DB2 database structure and data without contraint issues

Tags: sql, db2, data-migration

I want to move a DB2 10.1 database schema including tables, view, keys, sequences and its data to a new database on another network.

The new database is in a Production environment and because of security protocols, I cannot copy it directly across the networks.  The current database is in a non-Production test environment.

I'm looking to generate script or scripts which will recreate the database schema including the tables, view, keys, sequences and its data.  These scripts can then be transferred to the other network and run from there.

How can I do this?  I have looked at db2move and db2look, but this looks like I will have problems when inserting the data because of referential constraints and the sequencing of primary keys (want to keep the current key id as it is being used as a reference number by the business team, but it is auto generated in the database).

Thanks

Comment: db2move would create the scripts for the database structure and for moving the data. There are options to deal with generated keys, so you should be able to keep existing IDs. Would a redirected RESTORE from a database backup be an option as well?

Comment: A restore could be acceptable I will need to check to see if there will be differences in the backup.  Both databases are 10.1 though.    Some of the tables have auto generated keys while others do not.  I want to keep the IDs for all of the tables just to make sure that none of the foreign keys become corrupt.  Wasn't sure whether there was an option I wasn't aware of with db2move or db2look or whether there was another command/tool that could generate scripts that could be run to rebuild the database schema in another database.

Comment: The only thing with the backup would be that I think it would take everything when I'm only interested in copying the schema.  So would have to go through the backup and remove what is not needed.

Comment: Is there a way of running the backup command, but just for a schema?

Comment: There is, but with some restrictions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0057037.html